# How do i make one array out of two arrays containing different values

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array, compare

I have two arrays, one called `fetched_services`  and one called `fetched_companies`, they look like this:

**fetched_services**

```
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [child_services] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 153
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 137
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 138
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

**fetched_companies**

```
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [services] => Array
            (
                [0] => 25
                [1] => 102
            )
    )
)
```

What i want to achieve is to end up with an array like `fetched_services` but only having `child_services` with id of `fetched_companies["services"]`.

What i have tried is this:

```
$services = [];
$isFound = false;
foreach ($fetched_services as $fetched_service) {
  foreach ($fetched_service["child_services"] as $fetched_child_service) {
    $fetched_service["child_services"] = [];
    foreach ($fetched_companies as $fetched_company) {
      if( (in_array($fetched_child_service["id"],$fetched_company->services)) ) {
        $fetched_service["child_services"][] = $fetched_child_service;
        $isFound = true;
      }
    }
    if($isFound) {
      
      $services[] = $fetched_service;
      $isFound = false;
    }
  }
}
```

This outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [child_services] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 116
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [child_services] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 117
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

As you can see the resulting array have two arrays containing same id but the  `child_services` are different.

What i want to end up with is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [child_services] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 116
                        )

                )
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 117
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Where is `['id' => 11]` coming from in the resulting array? You said you wanted an array just like `fetched_services`, but the target output you've shared does not have the same structure.

Comment: I updated my question with where the id is. Thanks! It looks like this `$fetched_services = [
    'id' => 11,
    'child_services' => [
        ['id' => 25],
        ['id' => 137],
        ['id' => 102]
    ]
];`

Comment: Thanks, but there's still something unclear: your `$fetched_companies` variable appears to be an array. Should the child services be filtered with *all* services defined in this array? What does the 0 key refer to?

Comment: Yes. What i want is to check if the services contains the child_services[id], remove child_services if their id is not in the services array, and finally reconstruct the fetched_service array with child_services array. phew

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following: you'll have to give a clear example of input -> output by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear (I'll edit/delete this if/when you clarify, see my comment above), but you could probably make use of [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) by only keeping services that are present in said list (via [`in_array`](https://3v4l.org/1FSEo)):

```
$result = array_filter(
  $fetched_services['child_services'],
  fn(array $child_service): bool => in_array($child_service['id'], $fetched_companies[0]->services, true)
);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/1FSEo)